# Lipschitz transformation $(R^n)$

Tags: measure-theory

I am struggling trying to prove this exercise (Measure Theory problem):
If $T: \mathbf{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbf{R^n}$ is a Lipschitz transformation, then there is a constant C > 0 such that $|T(I)| \leq C |I|$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $I$? Some identity mapping?

Comment: I is an interval of $R^n$

Comment: So $I$ would be a Cartesian product of $n$  intervals of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Exactly, any idea?